# Grails doc - is it possible to include groovydoc for classes from plugin?

Tags: grails

we are using internal plugins to share domain classes between projects. Is it possible to include those domain classes in groovydoc/javadoc generated by "grails doc" command for final project? Is there any suggested way of handling that? We are currently on Grails 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
[MyDomain|api:foo.bar.MyDomain]
```

Comment: Such link from page generated from gdoc works correctly. But if we go to the package of this class in groovydoc directly, classes from plugins are not listed. Also if parameter of method in groovydoc is class from plugin, link points to not existing page: "DomainClass" instead of "foo.bar.DomainClass"